# Possible Bug in codecs.decode using ROT13

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

Python 3.5.1 on Ubuntu

```
>>> from codecs import decode
>>> s = 'string'
>>> b = b'bytes'
>>> decode(b, 'utf8')
'bytes'
>>> decode(s, 'utf8')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding with 'utf8' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str')
```

so far everything behaves as expected. But when I try to use ROT13 encoding I get:

```
>>> decode(s, 'rot13')
'fgevat'
>>> decode(b, 'rot13')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/encodings/rot_13.py", line 18, in decode
    return (input.translate(rot13_map), len(input))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: decoding with 'rot13' codec failed (TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'dict')
```

As @snakecharmerb points out ROT13 en/decoding is only supposed to work on strings.
The exception Message though, is still wrong since it states, that a bytes-like object was expected even when a bytes-like object was actually passed, and mentions some dictionary the user did not create.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding  the ROT13 codec, the [Python 3.5 docs state](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-transforms):

> The following codec provides a text transform: a str to str mapping.
>   It is not supported by str.encode() (which only produces bytes
>   output).

that is, you can only pass unicode strings (`str` objects) when encoding to ROT13 and you will only get `str` objects back.

This is different from Python 2.x, when ROT13 was treated the same as other codecs.  ROT13 was not ported to Python 3 initially, because ROT13 does not encode a unicode string to bytes - it just swaps letters around.  It as reinstated, as a text transform in Python 3.2 and 3.4.  The full story is in [this bug report](https://bugs.python.org/issue7475).

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. The Error message is still completely wrong though.

Comment: @0x539 Yes, I it looks like some implementation detail percolating up - probably should be caught and re-raised as something that makes more sense.